# Printing like a character but sorting like numeric in Shiny and DataTable

Tags: r, sorting, datatables, shiny

I would like to sort a DataTable column that is formatted with dollars (and thus is a character). I have used `scales::dollar()` for formatting. This converts the field to a character which causes sorting problems (for instance, `"$8" > "$10"`).

How can I sort the field as if it were numeric? Alternatively, can I keep the field as numeric and just print with dollar formatting?

**app.R** (requires Shiny 0.10.2)

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$foo_table <- renderDataTable({
    x <- seq(8000, 12000, by = 1000)
    x <- scales::dollar(x)
    d <- data.frame(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    d
  })
}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    mainPanel(dataTableOutput("foo_table"))
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A bit late, but the [DT Package](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) now has format functions, including formatCurrency:

```
# format the columns A and C as currency, and D as percentages
datatable(m) %>% formatCurrency(c('A', 'C')) %>% formatPercentage('D', 2)
```

From the Functions page:

> Under the hood, these formatting functions are just wrappers for the rowCallback option to generate the appropriate JavaScript code.
>   Similarly, there is a formatDate() function that can be used to format date/time columns. It has a method argument that takes values from a list of possible conversion methods: toDateString, toISOString, toLocaleDateString, toLocaleString, toLocaleTimeString, toString, toTimeString, toUTCString.

Answer (score 1):

As of DataTables 1.10 you should be able to sort with currency http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type. In options it should suffice to give a `type = 'num-fmt'` to column index zero. This would correspond to `columnDefs = list(list(targets = c(0), type = "num-fmt"))` in `options.
The following should work but does not for me:

```
library(shiny)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$foo_table <- renderDataTable({
    x <- seq(8000, 12000, by = 1000)
    x <- scales::dollar(x)
    d <- data.frame(x)
    d
  }
  , options = list(
    columnDefs = list(list(targets = c(0), type = "num-fmt"))
  )
  )
}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  mainPanel(dataTableOutput("foo_table"))
)
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Maybe @yihui can shed some light on the issue.

Comment: This option to `renderDataTable` is the type of thing I was looking for. Can't figure out why this doesn't work. Perhaps this can be accomplished through literal JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

The mixedsort and mixedorder functions in package gtools can do that:

```
x <- seq(8000, 12000, by = 1000)
x <- scales::dollar(x)
d <- data.frame(x)

 mixedsort(d$x) # not much of a test but also give same results with mixedsort(rev(d$x))

[1] $8,000  $9,000  $10,000 $11,000 $12,000
Levels: $10,000 $11,000 $12,000 $8,000 $9,000
```

Notice that your data.frame call created factors. You might not want that and if not should include stringsAsFactors=FALSE. I do not see any mention in the help page about commas and so you might want to apply a `gsub("[,]", "", d$x)` before the `mixedsort`.

Comment: `gtools::mixedsort()` looks very handy. But that doesn't solve the issue of getting the dataTable in Shiny to sort properly.

Comment: Sorry. I'm not a sufficiently experienced Shiny user to parse that statement